# XSLT woes, or fun with XPath, text(), and sum(), a tragedy in three acts

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to do basic word counts of html files, excluding some elements that shouldn't be included. A sample file might look like the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:epub='http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='standard.css' />
        <title>Book title</title>
    </head>
    <body class='contents'>
        <h3>Chapter 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</p>
        <blockquote>et dolore magna</blockquote>
        <p>aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should ignore everything not in the body (usually this only means excluding the `<title/>`), but there are also so tags I'd like to exclude in the body as well. Mostly the leading headers. The number of allowed tags is small enough (I think) that it would not matter to me if I were whitelisting the allowed or blacklisting the disallowed.

I'm using a command-line tool for Windows that I no longer remember where I got it, called xsltproc. It claims these versions:

```
xsltproc --version
Using libxml 20708, libxslt 10126 and libexslt 815
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20706, libxslt 10126 and libexslt 815
libxslt 10126 was compiled against libxml 20706
libexslt 815 was compiled against libxml 20706
```

I do not know if it this does XSLT 2+, I'm only familiar with XSLT 1.0. Which I seem to have to relearn every time I have to deal with it.

For any given p|blockquote|cite element in my html files, I can count the number of words (separated by spaces) with an expression something like this (shamelessly stolen off of another SO post):

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-length(normalize-space(.))
-
 string-length(translate(normalize-space(.),' ','')) +1
 "/>
```

Substituting valid (namespaced, ugh!) XPath into the normalize-space()'s works, usually something of the form //ns:p/text().

But this only gets me the per-`<p>` counts. I can toss that into an xsl for-each, too, and get a big long list of each of the per-paragraph counts. But what I'd really like is a total... and seeing as how there is a sum(), it should be easy. But I'm goofing it up somehow.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' 
                xmlns:h='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
                xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" cdata-section-elements="style"/>
    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <a>
        <q><xsl:value-of select="//h:body//text()"/></q>
        <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(normalize-space(//h:p/text())) - string-length(translate(normalize-space(//h:p/text()), ' ', '')) + 1"/>
        </b>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above at least ignores the h3 tag. But it limits it to the first pargraph and no others, giving a result of 5 instead of the expected 27. Returning to using the dot xpath seems to get multiple tags' worth of text nodes, but gives the anomalous value of 29 (should be 34? or 32 if only somehow getting children of the body element?).

Is there a way to get a sane value or are these just the wrong tools for the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `libxslt` processor supports only XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 1.0 it is not possible to sum calculated values directly.

OTOH, the processor supports many extension functions - for example. the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` function which makes producing word counts much easier.

Try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
exclude-result-prefixes="x exsl str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/x:html">
    <xsl:variable name="word-counts">
        <xsl:for-each select="x:body//*[not(starts-with(name(), 'h'))]/text()">
            <n>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(str:tokenize(., ' '))"/>
            </n>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($word-counts)/n)"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on the command line in Windows, then you're not constrained to the ancient xsltproc/libxslt, which only implements XSLT 1.0. For example you could use Saxon which implements XSLT 3.0. You could then do:

```
<xsl:template match="/x:html">
    <out>{count(//*[f:is-included(.)]/text()/tokenize())}</out>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="f:is-included" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="e" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="exists($e[self::p or self::q or self::r...])"/>
</xsl:function>
```